# Async Chaining Pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider following case:

```
var Calc = function () {
   // proprties
   this.value = 0

   // handler's
   this.Add = (__value) => { this.value = this.value + __value; return this }
   this.Subtract = (__value) => { this.value = this.value - __value; return this }
}

var = (new Calc()).Add(2).Subtract(1) // console.log() => 1
```

but if you wrap Object in async await something like

```
var Calc = async function () {
   // proprties
   this.value = 0

   // handler's
   this.Add = async (__value) => { this.value = this.value + __value; return this }
   this.Subtract = async (__value) => { this.value = this.value - __value; return this }
}

(await new Calc()).Add(2).Subtract(1) // console.log() => undefined
(await (await new Calc()).Add(2)).Subtract(1) // console.log() => 1
```

I know the reason as Promise is returned it need to be resolved for that you just wrap your code inside () and once statement is executed you can continue chain.

What i am looking for.

```
await newCalc().Add(2).Subtract(1) // console.log() => 1
```

Comment: As very first comment: why is your `Calc` not a class?

Comment: those operations are not async

Comment: [you can't use top level await yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)

Comment: Just as a general question, is there any particular reason you're using Promises for a Calculator? You *can* if you're getting numbers through network requests, but if you're just calculating numbers there doesn't seem to be any reason for it.

Comment: Being blunt here: just putting `async` in front of anything does not make sense. Even if those ops `Add` and `Subtract` `async` why does the `Calc` function is `async`. And double `await` why? what is it that u need to accomplish here.

Comment: I think you're gonna have to store unresolved promises locally (like `this.__promise = xxx`) and also "await" them in each of those functions manually as well for what you want to achieve. I don't think there's a "native" way to achieve this (i.e. async chaining).

Comment: Exactly ambianBeing why double await? and guys actual code do location tracking and mapping those locations with other saved location's in a cache.  have to replace it with something short and I came with calculator example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the caveat that `await` can only be used inside an `async` function, the kind of API you want is possible, it's just a bit more complicated.

Plenty of libraries such as `knex`, `jQuery` and `nightmare.js` implement chaining to compose asynchronous operation. But the chainable methods are not asynchronous. Instead, the asynchronous operation is only carried out at the end of operations (when you want the result) but the methods themselves are synchronous. In the case of `knex` for example, the asynchronous operation is only carried out when `.then()` is called.

Here's one way you can do it:

```
function Calc () {
    this.operations = [];
    this.value = 0;
}

Calc.prototype = {
    add: function (x) {
        // schedule a function that performs async addition:
        this.operations.push(() => {
            return new Promise(ok => {
                ok(this.value + x);
            });
        });
        return this;
    },
    subtract: function (x) {
        // schedule a function that performs async subtraction:
        this.operations.push(() => {
            return new Promise(ok => {
                ok(this.value - x);
            });
        });
        return this;
    },
    // THIS IS WHERE WE DO OUR MAGIC
    then: async function (callback) {
        // This is finally where we can execute all our
        // scheduled async operations:
        this.value = 0;
        for (let i=0; i<this.operations.length; i++) {
            this.value = await operations[i]();
        }
        return callback(this.value); // since the await keyword will call our
                                     // then method it is the responsibility of
                                     // this method to return the value.
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
async function main () {
    let x = await new Calc().add(2).subtract(1);
    console.log(x);
}
main();
```

Note that the code above is functionally equivalent to:

```
new Calc().add(2).subtract(1).then(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Exactly the same that I started to write... Nice code & explanation, +1

Comment: Also, don't forget to empty the `operations` array when `then` is called, and all operations done

Comment: @FZs It depends on what you want to do. Knex for example doesn't empty the operations array (or whatever it uses internally for it) so that you can reuse your query object to fetch the data again from the db

Comment: I agree, but in this context, keeping it will result in some weird behavior. Just try when the `Add` and `Subtract` modifies `c`: `const c=new Calc();c.Add(2).Subtract(1);c.then();c.then();c.then(()=>console.log(c.value))`, it will log 3!